# MySQL OR with priority

Tags: mysql

There is a customer table and a price table. Each customer can have a negotiated price. What would be the most effective way to load the price list for a customer?

```
+-----------+--------------+
| accountid | account_name |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 | test         |
+-----------+--------------+

+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| priceid | accountid | productid | price |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|       1 |         1 |        10 |  9.99 |
|       1 |           |        10 | 11.99 |
|       2 |           |        12 |  5.99 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

The result shoud be:

```
+-----------+-------+
| productid | price |
+-----------+-------+
|        10 |  9.99 |
|        12 |  5.99 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: If you show us some ways, we can tell you which is most effective. Failing that, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that right now the only solution I'm aware of would be with outside MySQL. ( Load all products and decide for each product it's price, but this is not time effective )

Comment: Hence the link provided

Comment: This query:
SELECT * FROM `product_price` WHERE ( `product_price`.`accountid` = '1' OR `product_price`.`accountid` = '' ) 
returns all the results, but some products are duplicated. The results should be somehow grouped. The other way would be to check if `product_price`.`accountid` = '1' returns zero results, than should be a fallback for `product_price`.`accountid` = ''

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question by editing it

Comment: I see the same productId with two different prices, is the row with the accountid=1 a discounted price for that account? If yes you have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next query for your problem:

```
-- Select price list for account no. 1
SELECT productid, price 
FROM price_table
WHERE accountid = 1
UNION -- append by rest pricelist
SELECT productid, price 
FROM price_table 
WHERE 
    accountid = '' AND -- for prices without accountid 
    NOT EXISTS ( -- and nave not price specified for account id
        SELECT productid 
        FROM price_table pt 
        WHERE pt.accountid = 1 AND pt.productid = price_table.productid
    );
```

P.S. in price_table prefer to set accountid field as nullable int instead varchar. Look example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c91707b5de3854b9d6c2764830cfd25c)